# Why does the controller in spring boot only accept data of json type and doesn't accept data submitted from thymeleaf form?

Tags: spring, jpa, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I can't submit the form through the index page, but I can submit it from the Postman.

When submitting from the postman with the content-type application/json, everything works. When submitting from the form, I'm getting:

Browser:
"There was an unexpected error (type=Unsupported Media Type, status=415).
Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported"

Console:
 Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Why does it require json data? Also is my form correctly sending the object towns with the data(the name) to the controller?

Here is my form from index page, it is written using thymeleaf:

```
<form action="" th:action="@{/addTown}" th:object="${towns}" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" th:value="*{name}" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add"/>
</form>
```

The controller:

```
public class Controller {
    @Autowired
    ServiceTowns serviceTowns;
    @PostMapping(value="/addTown")
    public ModelAndView addTown(@Valid @RequestBody Town town) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("success");
        mv.addObject(serviceTowns.addTown(judete));
        return mv;
    }
}
```

The service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ServiceTowns {
    @Autowired
    RepTown repTown;
    public Towns addTown(Towns towns){
        return RepTown.save(towns);
    }
}
```

The repository:

```
public interface RepTown extends JpaRepository<Towns, Integer> {

}
```

The model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="towns")
public class Towns {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    public Towns(){}
    public Towns(String name){
        this.name= name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[handle form submission spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/)

maybe you are missing some dependencies, this link could be helpful to solve your problem.